# ES6 Class Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm dabbling with the new ES6 `Class` keyword and I have a funky scenario that gives me some infinite loop and eventually `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Here's my class:

```
'use strict';

class Group {

 set name(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }

}

module.exports = Group;
```

and I'm calling it with this mocha test:

```
'use strict';

const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Group model', function() {

  var Group;

  it('should not blow up when requiring', function() {
     Group = require('../../models/group');
     expect(Group).to.not.be.undefined;
  });

  describe('create()', function() {
    it('should fail with no parameters', function() {
      const expected = new Error();

      var group = new Group();
      //group.name('myName');
      group.name = 'myName';

    });

  });

});
```

When I run my mocha test I get this printout:

```
 1) Group model create() should fail with no parameters:
     RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
      at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:335:15)
      at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:89:5)
      at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:684:5)
      at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:694:8)
      at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:292:12)
      at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:278:5)
      at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:207:11)
      at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:618:40)
      at Console.log (console.js:36:16)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:122:13)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
      at Group.name (models/group.js:123:15)
```

What is causing this infinite loop and how can i get around it?

FYI I'm on node.js 5.1.0

Comment: You currently have a method called `name`, as well as a property called `name`. Try changing the method to `setName`.

Comment: Actually, he's using a property with a setter which calls itself recursively. If you mean to have a backing field, name it differently.

Comment: Ahh i'm an idiot. changing `this.name` to `this._name` works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your setter property is recursively setting itself. Try something more along the lines of this...

```
class Group {

 set name(newName) {
    this._name = newName;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

}
```

Comment: This is just mind numbing. Why would they design it in this way?